# jQuery delaying a script

Tags: jquery

I'm using this js to make two divs the same height which works fine with static content, but when images/content is being loaded in dynamically the height is being set as 0px because I imagine the script is firing before the content has been pulled. Is there a way to delay this from firing for a few seconds so the correct height gets set? Tried timeout function but couldnt get it to work

```
// make stuff the same height
equalheight = function (container) {

var currentTallest = 0,
 currentRowStart = 0,
 rowDivs = new Array(),
 $el,
 topPosition = 0;
$(container).each(function () {

    $el = $(this);
    $($el).height('auto')
    topPostion = $el.position().top;

    if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
        for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
            rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
        }
        rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
        currentRowStart = topPostion;
        currentTallest = $el.height();
        rowDivs.push($el);
    } else {
        rowDivs.push($el);
        currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) :     (currentTallest);
    }
    for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
        rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
    }
});
}


$(window).load(function () { equalheight('.equal'); });
$(window).resize(function () { equalheight('.equal'); });
```

Comment: Are you using AJAX to load content?

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: if you are not using $(document).ready() then just wrap your code with this and see what happens

Comment: Yup, how is the content being dynamically loaded?  Could you just trigger these functions once that load has finished?

Comment: I assume the dynamic content you refer to is from the .load jQuery call, although this doesn't seem to include a url from which you're pulling content?

Comment: The code you have won't do anything until it is called, so where is it called?

Comment: Yea it looks like the content is being pulled in by using ajax in a huge js file. I guess I'll have to fire these functions in that file somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Your answer does not provide enough information to provide a definite answer, I'm going to jump the gun and assume your tried `setTimeout` where you are calling the function, if this is the case then instead, try the `setTimeout` in the function itself like this.

```
// make stuff the same height

equalheight = function (container) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {  // Start setTimeout

        var currentTallest = 0,
            currentRowStart = 0,
            rowDivs = new Array(),
            $el,
            topPosition = 0;
        $(container).each(function () {

            $el = $(this);
            $($el).height('auto')
            topPostion = $el.position().top;

            if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
                for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
                    rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
                }
                rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
                currentRowStart = topPostion;
                currentTallest = $el.height();
                rowDivs.push($el);
            } else {
                rowDivs.push($el);
                currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
            }
            for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
                rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
            }
        });
    }, 5000); // End setTimeout
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Why when you select your element you make that :

```
$el = $(this);
$($el).height('auto');
```

You can't select a selector.
you just have to write:

```
$el = $(this);    
$el.height('auto');
```

I don't know if I'm obvious by saying that but it seems weird.

Then for your problem you should try to do set the height in your ajax success.
And check your selector to be sure it is correct.

Comment: You are correct, but this has nothing to do with the issue raised, and therefore a incorrect answer.

Comment: And is OP using ajax?